# cannot access my new appspot app

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

i have created a new appspot application in google appengine. but when tried to access the app via its url  it returns 404 error. Are there any additional settings need to be done?

following is my app url [app](http://inspironinventory.appspot.com/)

Comment: did it work on localhost? do you have a hander for the default url (/)? What is it? Post the code

Comment: Have you uploaded any code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to deploy an app with some code.

Comment: Thanks for the @aschmid00 that sorted.